# Abelianized fundamental group

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $P$ be the projective plane and let $nP$ be the connected sum of $n$ copies of the projective plane. Show that the abelianized fundamental group $\pi_{1}(nP)/[\pi_1,\pi_1]$ is the direct sum of a free abelian group of rank $n-1$ and $Z_2$

I know that $\pi_1(nP)=<a_1,a_2,...,a_n|a_1^2a_2^2...a_n^2=1>$

Can you help me or hint plz?

Comment: Are you aware that $\pi_1(X)/[\pi_1,\pi_1]\cong H_1(X)$ for all path-connected spaces $X$?

Comment: Daniel/ I didn't know.. Can you give me link related to it?

Comment: Algebraic topology by Hatcher Theorem 2A.1 is probably a good place to read this.

Comment: thx a lot 4 ur help